# Placing two divs one below another

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with placing two divs one below another.

I tried out some solutions found in Stackoverflow like below.
But Nothing seems to be working.

Code:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

#up {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

#down {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="up"></div>
  <div id="down"></div>
</div>
```

Here's My Attempt,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pagqx/198/)

Helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by an up down manner. What is your end goal?

Comment: I need to place two divs one below another

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Pagqx/199/

Comment: @shmiddty This is what i want.!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the CSS.  DIV tags are block elements and would naturally flow down the page.  You are floating them which would cause them to be displayed side by side.

Especially remove the "float" attributes.

Comment: This. Also, the `absolute` is screwing it up, too, because it will default to a location of `0,0`, regardless of whether there's an element there already.

Answer (score 1):

That's how DIV's work by default, just remove your css. See a working example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMh3C/1/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="up"></div>
<div id="down"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: @Shmiddty It's there just so you can see as an example on the jsfiddle mkay?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you want the outer div to be greater than the height of the page, but that's what this does:

```
#DivSlider
{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    height:170%;
    background-color:green;
}

#DivHome
{
    height:26%;
    background-color:orange;
    border:1px solid black; /* You were missing the 'px' here */
}

#DivSkills
{
    height:25%;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}​
```