# Why does an image of position:absolute have no height? When I can see in the browser it has height

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to understand why a div with `display:block` will not sit under another div with `display:block`

My mark-up is this:

```css
.container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.container .text-left{
  position: absolute;
  top:35rem;
  left:35rem
}

.container .text-right{
  position: absolute;
  top:35rem;
  right:35rem
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <img src="/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="text_left">
    <h2>HEADING 1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" >
  <img src="/image2.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="text_right">
    <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying all sorts of stuff to make this work - overflows etc - but can't seem to get the second display block div to sit under the first.

**EDIT:** It seems that if you put position:absolute element/s inside a position:relative element - that may have height due to that element being an image - the absolute element/s removes this height. So you need to add it back in as height: X.

But why??

Is this due legacy mark up - using absolutes in ways not designed for?

Why would the browser not take into consideration the image height as default. And we could override this if needed.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

thanks

Comment: This question is Already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750598/placing-two-divs-one-below-another?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4):

The reason you have lost height is because `position:absolute;` removes element from the flow, therefore your parent container won't be able to use it to work out its height. It's not legacy markup, it's part of the scope.

[A quick excerpt from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

> The trade-off (and most important thing to remember) about absolute positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute positioning. Its overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of your site.

If for whatever reason you are required to have that specific element as `position:absolute;` your next best bet would be to adjust the parent container using JavaScript/jQuery, however that might be a bulky fix.

My suggestion would be to try and achieve your preferred layout without using the absolute positioning, and then if you get stuck, post another question here explaining your desired layout and current code trying to achieve it.

---

## EDIT

That being said, if the mentioned JavaScript/jQuery solution does not sound to bulky to you, you could try the following:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'padding-top': $(this).find('img').height()+'px'
    });
});
```

This will add `padding-top` to the container based on the image size. Alternative, you could add an empty div below the image and adjust its height based on the image size.

Comment: Thanks. But my image which is the position:relative/parent of the absolute element has a height - the image.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work just make the `img` and `test_*` position to `relative` instead of `absolute`. Why ? Position absolute removes element from the flow, that means that because all your `container`'s childrens are `absolute`, it is like your container has no content, that's why it collapse.

```css
.container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.container .text_left{
  position: absolute;
  top:90%;
  left:5%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .text_right{
  position: absolute;
  top:90%;
  right:5%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
  <div class="text_left">
    <h2>HEADING 1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
  <div class="text_right">
    <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the text should "float" over the images with the absolute:position. You have the text in a relative position.

Comment: In that case, juste make the image relative, but keep the text absolute. I updated my answer, please re-run the code. Maybe this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks but the images need to sit on top off each other.